# c3p0 Deadlock detection - thread running too frequently

Tags: hibernate, deadlock, connection-pooling, c3p0

We are using Hibernate and c3p0 connection pooling library. So far, this combination worked great until recently when we decided to increase the maxPoolSize to 1000 and do a lot of stress testing of our application. The peak load of our application is causing the DB to respond very slowly and as a consequence the Deadlock Detector of c3p0 is time and again spitting the APPARENT DEADLOCK warning.

Based on c3p0 documentation, we changed the maxAdministrativeTaskTime to 10 minutes assuming that the Deadlock detection happens once every 30 minutes ( Code indicates the Deadlock detection frequency is thrice that of maxAdministrativeTaskTime).

However, on analysis of the c3p0 logs, the Deadlock Detection Thread is running more frequently than 30 minutes. The relevant portion of the logs is attached. Surprisingly the frequency is not uniform.

```
Line 573745: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:47:52,492 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 573746: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:47:52,512 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 574292: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:49:12,493 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 574293: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:49:12,513 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 575004: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:50:32,494 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 575005: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:50:32,511 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 576062: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:51:52,495 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 576063: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:51:52,536 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 576720: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:53:12,496 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 576721: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:53:12,516 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 594087: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:55:52,550 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 594088: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:55:52,569 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 594753: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:57:12,550 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 594754: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:57:12,572 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 595624: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:58:32,552 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 595625: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:58:32,570 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 596416: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:59:52,552 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 596417: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 04:59:52,572 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Line 611011: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 05:02:22,556 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Line 611012: [Timer-2] 2013-06-26 05:02:22,577 WARN [null] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@662cee3b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
```

Can someone explain this anomaly?

Comment: ok. so sorry about my initial answer below, which was not so good. i've fixed the mistaken part. looking more carefully now, there's lots that is freaky about this. not only are you seeing deadlocks unexpectedly frequently, but the deadlocks that you are seeing ought not have been deadlocks at all, the "Complete Status:" is empty. There should be dumps of the tasks in the Thread pool and their stack traces. there are not. (is your logger truncating multiline log items?)

Answer (score 3):

<s>`maxAdministrativeTaskTime` does not affect the thread pool's deadlock detector; it just bounds the length that a single task is allowed to take before the pool tries to `interrupt()` it. one (*hackish!, ugly!, not advised!*) way to try to avoid APPARENT DEADLOCKs would be to set this to a SHORT interval, so that slow tasks get interrupted rather than hanging so long that the pool decides it is stuck. Please see some discussion [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime).</s>

thanks to the questioner (by e-mail), i double-checked my own %$^*&! code, and the deadlock detection interval *is* affected by `maxAdministrativeTaskTime`. as the question suggests, it ought to be 3 × `maxAdministrativeTaskTime`. so the mystery deepens.

it's worth understanding what the deadlock detector does. c3p0 maintains a Thread pool, `numHelperThreads` big. the deadlock detector periodically notes all tasks Threads in the pool are running, then sleeps a while, and then checks again. if *none* of the tasks has completed, i.e. the active tasks remain exactly the same as during the last check, then a deadlock is declared. the interval over which c3p0 expects some task to complete is 10 seconds, and not configurable for now. it could be made configurable.

you might post some examples of the APPARENT DEADLOCKs you see. c3p0 prints a lot of information to help you understand what might be hanging.

here are two suggestions to reduce APPARENT DEADLOCKs under very heavy load:

1. are the deadlocks you observe related to Connection acqusistion? if so, and if you have not already, please upgrade to c3p0-0.9.2.1 or the latest 0.9.5 prerelease.
2. have you tried increasing `numHelperThreads` as you've scaled up your load? if some tasks are very slow, c3p0 won't declare a deadlock unless all the Threads are blocked by the slow tasks. if there are enough Threads so that nimbler tasks are still getting executed, you'll not see deadlocks.

i hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it, but 1000 connections is quite a lot, does your c3p0 configuration reflect this high number of connections? My experience is that the default settings are good for a lower number of connections.
I suggest reading the [c3po documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), especially the part under "Other DataSource Configuration".